# Scaling factor to automatically center of a mesh?

Tags: opengl, graphics, computational-geometry, mesh

Tring Vu here.  I am trying to develop a program that automatically centers a mesh.  My program currently takes in .obj file and calculates these important values as of right now:

-maximum x,y,z of mesh
-minimum x.y,z position of mesh;

I am trying to figure out a to calculate the camera position given those parameters.  So far I use the bounding box to center the mesh and calculate the radius:

```
            offset_x = (max_x + min_x)/2;
            offset_y = (max_y + min_y)/2;
            offset_z = (max_z + min_z)/2;

            radius = 0.0;
            for each vertex v
                v = v - offset;
                if(v.abs() > radius) radius = v.abs;
```

Here's my lookat and projection code:

```
            gluLookAt (0.0, 0.0,radius,
                       0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                       0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

            ...
            GLdouble znear = 1.0;
            GLdouble zfar = znear + 2*radius;
            GLdouble aspect = (GLdouble) w/(1.0f*h);

            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
            gluPerspective(50.0, aspect, znear, zfar);
```

However, due to asymmetry in bounding box, this method doesn't good results.  I am thinking of somehow scaling the mesh to [-1,-1,-1] to [1,1,1].  However, I don't what the scaling factor should be.  I was thinking of I might have to split up the mesh into 8 parts depending on the vertex, and then scale by the appropriate min/max.  But I am not sure if that'll work.  Any ideas?

Comment: "doesn't good results" is not enough information to help us diagnose. Anyway, I would first question the position of the eye, "against" the object. Why not `0.0, 0.0, 3 * radius` or so ? (Also adjust `znear`, `zfar`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (OPENGLWIDTH, OPENGLHEIGHT and OPENGLDEPTH are #defines).  This scales to fill 90% of the screen (1.8 factor):

```
        double xScale = 1.0, xOffset, yOffset, zOffset;
        double range = maxX - minX;

        if(range > 0.1)
        {
            xScale = 1.8 * OPENGLWIDTH / range;
        }

        double yScale = 1.0;
        range = maxY - minY;

        if(range > 0.1)
        {
            yScale = 1.8 * OPENGLHEIGHT / range;
        }

        double zScale = 1.0;
        range = maxZ - minZ;

        if(range > 0.1)
        {
            zScale = 1.8 * OPENGLDEPTH / range;
        }

        if(yScale < xScale) xScale = yScale;
        if(zScale < xScale) xScale = zScale;

        xOffset = xScale * (maxX + minX) / 2.0;
        yOffset = xScale * (maxY + minY) / 2.0;
        zOffset = xScale * (maxZ + minZ) / 2.0;
```